# SVG rhombus expand animation when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I'm building a website and the customer wants a rhombus/diamond shaped button with text in it, and when it is clicked it should become bigger and push down the other content.

I guess the best way to do it would be in SVG, but I have no experience with that. This would be easy if it wasn't for the rhombus typed shape, which is giving me a small headache :)

Is there a easy solution to this or could you guide me in the right direction?
This is what the costumer wants:
[rhombus button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztVB.jpg)

Comment: you can try using svg in background - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score -1):

Try d3 js. You can achieve almost anything you want with only js.

You can check the [gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) for examples.

There might be better ways to do it.